# How to execute method on object of Class<?>

Tags: java, class, reflection

I wonder is it possible to execute method from class on runtime on object of Class?

At first: I have method that returns me a class:

```
public static Class<?> getClassById(Long id) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if(d.id == 1L) {
        return First.class;
    } else if(d.id ==2L) {
        return Second.class;
    } else if(d.id ==3L) {
        return Third.class;
    } else {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

Second: The way I execute it:

`Index.GetClassById(1)` which should return me Class. Now I would like to execute method `myMethod()` from that class. By the way, each class of (First, Second, Third) have this `myMethod()` method.

Please help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A `Class` object is an instance of the type representing your class. This means that `First.class.equals(new First())` will always return false.

What you want is to create an object based on your class and on that class call your method `myMethod()`, assuming that you classes (First, Second, Third) have a default constructor:

```
Class clazz = Index.getClassById(1);
First first = (First)clazz.newInstance();
first.myMethod();
```

The drawback on this approach is that you have to cast the object explecitly.

For this to relay work neatly you should define an interface that defines `myMethod()`:

```
public interface MyInterface {
  void myMethod();
}
public class First implements MyInterface {
...
}
public class Second implements MyInterface {
...
}
public class Third implements MyInterface {
...
}
```

Then you can define your method from above as:

```
public static Class<MyInterface> getClassById(Long id) throws ClassNotFoundException {
    if(d.id == 1L) {
        return First.class;
    } else if(d.id ==2L) {
        return Second.class;
    } else if(d.id ==3L) {
        return Third.class;
    } else {
        throw new ClassNotFoundException();
    }
}
```

And call it like this:

```
Class<MyInterface> clazz = Index.getClassById(1);
MyInterface instance = clazz.newInstance();
instance.myMethod();
```

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I need.

Answer (score 1):

Since you have a class instance, you can get it's object instance and then invoke it's method by method's name:

```
//empty patameters array, to specify the method signature
Class noparams[] = {};
//get the class
Class cls = getClassById(1L);
//get an instance of the class
Object obj = cls.newInstance();
//get some method of the class by it's signatute (name and input parameters)
Method method = cls.getDeclaredMethod("myMethod", noparams);
//invoke this method without parameters
method.invoke(obj, null);
```

But the solution with some common interface is preferable, then you can get an instance of this interface and call it in usual way.

Comment: It use to hard of reflection. And passing method name as a String it is not really my way of programming. But thanks for answer.

Answer (score 1):

The problem that you talk about is a design pattern called abstract design pattern in which all your classes.

Step 1
Create an interface for Shapes.

Shape.java

```
public interface Shape {
   void draw();
}
```

Step 2
Create concrete classes implementing the same interface.

Rectangle.java

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape {

   @Override
   public void draw() {
   System.out.println("Inside Rectangle::draw() method.");
  }
 }
```

Square.java

```
public class Square implements Shape {

   @Override
   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Inside Square::draw() method.");
   }
}
```

Circle.java

```
public class Circle implements Shape {

   @Override
   public void draw() {
      System.out.println("Inside Circle::draw() method.");
   }
}
```

Step 3
Create an interface for Colors.

Color.java

```
public interface Color {
   void fill();
}
```

Step4
Create concrete classes implementing the same interface.

Red.java

```
public class Red implements Color {

   @Override
   public void fill() {
      System.out.println("Inside Red::fill() method.");
   }
}
```

Green.java

```
public class Green implements Color {

   @Override
   public void fill() {
      System.out.println("Inside Green::fill() method.");
   }
}
```

Blue.java

```
public class Blue implements Color {

   @Override
   public void fill() {
      System.out.println("Inside Blue::fill() method.");
   }
}
```

Step 5
Create an Abstract class to get factories for Color and Shape Objects.

AbstractFactory.java

```
public abstract class AbstractFactory {
   abstract Color getColor(String color);
   abstract Shape getShape(String shape) ;
}
```

Step 6
Create Factory classes extending AbstractFactory to generate object of concrete class based on given information.

ShapeFactory.java

```
    public class ShapeFactory extends AbstractFactory {

       @Override
       public Shape getShape(String shapeType){

  if(shapeType == null){
     return null;
  }     

  if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("CIRCLE")){
     return new Circle();

  }else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("RECTANGLE")){
     return new Rectangle();

  }else if(shapeType.equalsIgnoreCase("SQUARE")){
     return new Square();
  }

  return null;
   }

   @Override
   Color getColor(String color) {
  return null;
    }
}
```

ColorFactory.java

```
public class ColorFactory extends AbstractFactory {

   @Override
   public Shape getShape(String shapeType){
  return null;
  }

   @Override
   Color getColor(String color) {

  if(color == null){
     return null;
  }     

  if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("RED")){
     return new Red();

  }else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("GREEN")){
     return new Green();

  }else if(color.equalsIgnoreCase("BLUE")){
     return new Blue();
  }

  return null;
   }
   }
```

Step 7
Create a Factory generator/producer class to get factories by passing an information such as Shape or Color

FactoryProducer.java

```
public class FactoryProducer {
   public static AbstractFactory getFactory(String choice){

  if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("SHAPE")){
     return new ShapeFactory();

  }else if(choice.equalsIgnoreCase("COLOR")){
     return new ColorFactory();
  }

  return null;
  }
}
```

Step 8
Use the FactoryProducer to get AbstractFactory in order to get factories of concrete classes by passing an information such as type.

AbstractFactoryPatternDemo.java

```
public class AbstractFactoryPatternDemo {
   public static void main(String[] args) {

  //get shape factory
  AbstractFactory shapeFactory = FactoryProducer.getFactory("SHAPE");

  //get an object of Shape Circle
  Shape shape1 = shapeFactory.getShape("CIRCLE");

  //call draw method of Shape Circle
  shape1.draw();

  //get an object of Shape Rectangle
  Shape shape2 = shapeFactory.getShape("RECTANGLE");

  //call draw method of Shape Rectangle
  shape2.draw();

  //get an object of Shape Square 
  Shape shape3 = shapeFactory.getShape("SQUARE");

  //call draw method of Shape Square
  shape3.draw();

  //get color factory
  AbstractFactory colorFactory = FactoryProducer.getFactory("COLOR");

  //get an object of Color Red
      Color color1 = colorFactory.getColor("RED");

      //call fill method of Red
      color1.fill();

      //get an object of Color Green
      Color color2 = colorFactory.getColor("Green");

      //call fill method of Green
      color2.fill();

      //get an object of Color Blue
      Color color3 = colorFactory.getColor("BLUE");

      //call fill method of Color Blue
      color3.fill();
    }
}
```

Step 9
Verify the output.

Inside Circle::draw() method.

Inside Rectangle::draw() method.

Inside Square::draw() method.

Inside Red::fill() method.

Inside Green::fill() method.

Inside Blue::fill() method.

Source :- http://www.tutorialspoint.com/design_pattern/abstract_factory_pattern.htm

Comment: Great answer. And I think that for more complicated purpose It will be a great solution. For mine exemple it is to much I think.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can. Having a `Class` you can now instantiate it

```
Object t = c.newInstance()
```

where `c` is the `Class<?>` returned from your method.

Now you can do

```
Method m = c.getMethod("your_method_name", optional_params_classes_here);
Object result = m.invoke(t, params_here_or_nothing);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid reflection as much I can.

Comment: You can't avoid reflection

Answer (score 0):

Use java reflections. Here is an example of calling 'concat' method of String s :

```
String s = "Hello, ";
Class myClass = s.getClass();

Method m = myClass.getDeclaredMethod("concat", String.class);
String result = (String)m.invoke(s, "world");

System.out.println(result);
```

Comment: I would like to avoid reflection as much I can.